# Lost My "Output" Window

Tags: python, python-2.7, window, spyder

I am sure I am using incorrect terminology, but hopefully you can grasp my meaning. I am working with Spyder python 2.7, and I have somehow lost my "output" window. I attached a screen shot. Formerly, there was a window, that, after having run my code, gave me the results of my code. How do I get this window back? I went to the view options, but had no such luck.

[image]

Comment: There's no screenshot.

Comment: Quick check: try view->console, this should make the console visible, then re-run the code.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Oh, I am terribly sorry.

Comment: @emh I tried that; it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) You have two options to make your console back (that's the right name of what you called as *output window* :)

1. Go to the `View` Menu and there from to `Windows and toolbars` and select either `Console` or `IPython console`.
2. If this doesn't solve your problem, just open a Windows terminal (i.e. `cmd.exe` from the `Start > Run` Window menu) and in it run this comnmand:

   ```
   spyder --reset
   ```

   and then restart Spyder again. That should solve your problem for sure.

Comment: The second alternative was successful. Thank you very much!